# Format of heading and signature in cover letter for job application

Tags: formatting, letters

Consider the following latex cover letter template.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\signature{John}
\address{John Doe \\ 
The University Department \\
Some Building \\
Some Station \\
Postcode and City \\
email}

\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Great University \\
Great Department \\
Great Street \\
Postcode and city \\
Country}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam:}

\lipsum[2-4]

\closing{Yours Faithfully,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

There are two things that annoy me from this letter.

1. There is a huge space above the sender's personal information. Ultimately, this means the letter doesn't fit in one page, which seems to be standard in STEM job applications. How can I reduce that space? I've seen similar questions asked here but the solutions given modify the format of my text.
2. The name is very far from the "Yours faithfully,". Is there a way to put it closer?

Comment: you can use `\enlargethispage{4cm}` to keep the signature on the first page. The space before the signatureis hardcoded, but you can cheat with `\closing{Yours Faithfully,\\[-6\medskipamount]\mbox{}}`. On the whole the class is rather restricted, they are better letter classes around, see e.g. https://ctan.org/topic/letter